# Yii2 посадка верстки на ActiveForm

Tags: php, yii2, вёрстка, activeform

Пытаюсь поставить шаблон на своей учебный проект на Yii.
Подскажите как посадить верстку на поле виджета ActiveForm?

В моей модели есть дополнительное свойство, пытаюсь его оформить как чекбокс, по умолчал выглядит и работает вот так

```
   <?= $setAll->field($permission,'set_on_all_folders')->checkbox();?>
```

Нужно оформить вот так:

```
<label class="switch switch-pill switch-label switch-success">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" checked>
                    <span class="switch-slider" data-checked="On" data-unchecked="Off"></span>
                </label>
```

Я конечно понимаю что можно сделать через name=ИмяМодели[ИмяСвойства], но врядли это оптимальный вариант. Как в боевых проектах на Yii впринципе садят верстку? Используют ли стандартные html хелперы и ActiveForm?

[image: изображение]

Answer (score 1):

> Используют ли стандартные html хелперы и ActiveForm?

Почему нет?

> Подскажите как посадить верстку на поле виджета ActiveForm?

В Вашем случае скорее всего нужно прописывать свой шаблон для checkbox.
Вот пример того, как это делается (взял [здесь](https://webformyself.com/yii2-activeform-chast-3/)):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'rememberMe')->checkbox([
 'template' => '<div class="col-md-1">{label}</div><div class="col-md-5">{input}</div><div class="col-md-6">{error}</div>'
])?>
```